# jQuery more less button in a datagrid, works when more clicked but not less

Tags: c#, jquery, gridview, datagrid

I have a button that is showing more or less of a content block in search results. When I click "More" it expands as needed, but nothing happens when I click "Less". I feel like it has to do with my `preventDefault(e)` line. Code is below...

```
$(".btnMore").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(e);
    if ($(this).attr('value', 'More')) {
        $(this).parent().prev().switchClass("abstractText", "abstractTextNoHeight", 500, "swing");
        $(this).attr('value', 'Less');
    }
    else if ($(this).attr('value', 'Less')) {
        $(this).parent().prev().switchClass("abstractTextNoHeight", "abstractText", 500, "swing");
        $(this).attr('value', 'More');
    }

});
```

Comment: what are the html definition of your grid, and what are the definitions of your css classes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the wrong way of using "attr()" to check for attribute value:

```
if($(this).attr("value", "More"))
```

Will set the value of "value" attribute to "More" and return `undefined`. What you need to do is this:

```
if($(this).attr("value") == "More")
```

or

```
if(this.getAttribute("value") == "More")
```

There is no need to use jQuery when JavaScript is sufficient. Notice the lack of `$()` around `this` - since you're using a JS function (`getAttribute`), you don't need to create a jQuery collection, which makes your code faster and simpler.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I ended up doing this...

`$(".btnMore").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(e);
        rowClicked = false;
        e.preventDefault(e);
        if ($(this).attr('value') == 'More') {
            $(this).parent().prev().switchClass("abstractText", "abstractTextNoHeight", 500, "swing");
            $(this).attr('value', 'Less');
        }
        else if ($(this).attr('value') == 'Less') {
            $(this).parent().prev().switchClass("abstractTextNoHeight", "abstractText", 500, "swing");
            $(this).attr('value', 'More');
        }
    });`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(".btnMore").click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault(e);
if ($(this).attr('value')=='More') {
    $(this).parent().prev().switchClass("abstractText", "abstractTextNoHeight", 500, "swing");
    $(this).attr('value', 'Less');
}
else if ($(this).attr('value')=='Less') {
    $(this).parent().prev().switchClass("abstractTextNoHeight", "abstractText", 500, "swing");
    $(this).attr('value', 'More');
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing it this way:

```
//more/less button
$(".btnMoreText a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    rowClicked = false;
    $(this).parent().parent().prev().switchClass("abstractText", "abstractTextNoHeight", 500, "swing");
    $(this).parent().addClass("hidden");
    $(this).parent().next().removeClass("hidden");
});

$(".btnLessText a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    rowClicked = false;
    console.log($(this).parent().parent().prev());
    $(this).parent().parent().prev().switchClass("abstractTextNoHeight", "abstractText", 500, "swing");
    $(this).parent().addClass("hidden");
    $(this).parent().prev().removeClass("hidden");
});
```